# Easy way to add -A/commit main/all submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-commit

By using `git add -A` and `git commit -a`, I can obviously add/commit all changes to the repo I'm currently situated in. However, is there a way to include *all* submodules in an add/commit and apply the same commit message to each?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alias. Make script: e.g. `~/supercommit.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [ -z $1 ]; then
    echo "You need to provide a commit message"
    exit
fi

git submodule foreach git add -A .
git submodule foreach git commit -am "$1"

git add -A .
git commit -am "$1"
```

And mark it executable (`chmod +x`). Now, create an alias:

```
git config alias.supercommit '!~/supercommit.sh "$@"; #'
```

That should do (I'll test it in a bit)

Comment: Seems to work - added some error checking for the git commit message and such.

Comment: @Qix Sweet, care to share?

Comment: This almost feels like it should be built in. Thanks for the script!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was asked and answered 9 years ago, and it helped me today when I was looking for the same thing. However, I faced some issues getting it working so I am posting this in order to help anyone else who may face the same issue.

issues :

- fails with "line 2: [: too many arguments"
- fails if any submodule has no changes

fixes :

- add quotes (") around $1 on line 2, without which a comment with multiple words is treated as multiple arguments
- check if submodule has staged changes before committing

updated code

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "You need to provide a commit message"
    exit
fi

git submodule foreach "
    git add -A .
    git update-index --refresh
    commits=\$(git diff-index HEAD)
    if [ ! -z \"\$commits\" ]; then
        git commit -am \"$1\"
    fi"

git add -A .
git commit -am "$1"
```